# Highlight when binding value changed

Tags: angular, typescript

I try make highlight line when binding variable (value) changed. In my Angular app I receive data from external service. This data are updated every 1 second. The structure looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "virtual": false,
        "isOffline": false,
        "isClosed": true,
        "isOpen": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "disabled": false,
        "virtual": false,
        "isOffline": false,
        "isClosed": true,
        "isOpen": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "disabled": false,
        "virtual": true,
        "isOffline": false,
        "isClosed": false,
        "isOpen": true
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "disabled": false,
        "virtual": false,
        "isOffline": false,
        "isClosed": true,
        "isOpen": false
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "disabled": true,
        "virtual": false,
        "isOffline": false,
        "isClosed": true,
        "isOpen": false
    },
]
```

In incoming data is a lot of objects (about 40-60). I think a solution based on two arrays is not efficient.

I need highlight only this variable was changed. For example when value changed from true to false (or false => true) I need to add red background under this value. Something like a Google Chrome inspector when DOM changed (changed was marked with yellow background)

My current HTML structure looks like:

```html
<div class="statuses" *ngIf="statuses">
    <div class="status" *ngFor="let status of data">
        <div class="row"><b>Id: </b>{{status.id}}</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Disabled: </b>{{status.disabled}}</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Virtual: </b>{{status.virtual}}</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Offline: </b>{{status.isOffline}}</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Close: </b>{{status.isClosed}}</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Open: </b>{{status.isOpen}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an directive implementing this behavior and add it to every div.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[appTextChange]'
})
export class TextChangeDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const initialTextContent = this.el.nativeElement.textContent;

    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', () => {
      if (this.el.nativeElement.textContent !== initialTextContent) {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```
<div class="statuses" *ngIf="statuses">
    <div class="status" *ngFor="let status of data">
        <div class="row" appTextChange><b>Id: </b>{{status.id}}</div>
        <div class="row" appTextChange><b>Disabled: </b>{{status.disabled}}</div>
        <div class="row" appTextChange><b>Virtual: </b>{{status.virtual}}</div>
        <div class="row" appTextChange><b>Offline: </b>{{status.isOffline}}</div>
        <div class="row" appTextChange><b>Close: </b>{{status.isClosed}}</div>
        <div class="row" appTextChange><b>Open: </b>{{status.isOpen}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcgade?file=src%2Ftext-change.directive.ts

Comment: Nice solution, but it implies that angular is reusing the DOM and changing the content of the divs. With his actual solution, the DOM is redrawn on each call (no trackBy function). Just something to keep in mind !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Angular only: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xk135i?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
interface Data {
  id: number;
  disabled: boolean;
  virtual: boolean;
  isOffline: boolean;
  isClosed: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
}

const data: Data[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    disabled: false,
    virtual: false,
    isOffline: false,
    isClosed: true,
    isOpen: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    disabled: false,
    virtual: false,
    isOffline: false,
    isClosed: true,
    isOpen: false,
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './main.html',
  imports: [NgIf, NgFor, ElementComponent],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  _data: Data[] = structuredClone(data);

  constructor() {
    interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        tap(
          () =>
            (this._data = this._data.map((item) => ({
              ...item,
              isOffline: !item.isOffline,
            })))
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  track(index: number, item: Data) {
    return item.id;
  }
}

<div class="statuses" *ngIf="_data?.length">
  <div class="status" *ngFor="let status of _data; trackBy: track">
    <app-element key="Id" [value]="status.id"></app-element>
    <app-element key="Disabled" [value]="status.disabled"></app-element>
    <app-element key="Virtual" [value]="status.virtual"></app-element>
    <app-element key="Offline" [value]="status.isOffline"></app-element>
    <app-element key="Close" [value]="status.isClosed"></app-element>
    <app-element key="Open" [value]="status.isOpen"></app-element>
  </div>
</div>


@Component({
  selector: 'app-element',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './element.component.html',
  imports: [NgIf, NgFor],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('highlightRed', [
      transition(
        '* => *',
        animate(
          '1500ms',
          keyframes([
            style({ backgroundColor: 'initial', boxShadow: 'none', offset: 0 }),
            style({
              backgroundColor: '#ff5c4c',
              boxShadow: '0 0 5px #ff5c4c',
              offset: 0.1,
            }),
            style({ backgroundColor: 'initial', boxShadow: 'none', offset: 1 }),
          ])
        )
      ),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class ElementComponent {
  @Input()
  key!: string;

  @Input()
  value!: string | number | boolean;
}

<p [@highlightRed]="value">
  <strong>{{ key }}:</strong> {{ value }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that 300 comparations are not very hard. You can take advantage of pairwise rxjs operator and make some like

```
this.obs$=timer(0,1000).pipe(
    switchMap(_=>{
      return this.dataService.getData()
    }),
    pairwise(),
    map(([previous,current])=>{
      return current.map((item:any,index:number)=>{
      return [item,
        {disabled: item.disabled!=previous[index].disabled,
        virtual: item.virtual!=previous[index].virtual,
        isOffline: item.isOffline!=previous[index].isOffline,
        isClosed: item.isClosed!=previous[index].isClosed,
        isOpen: item.isOpen!=previous[index].isOpen}
         ]
        }
      )
}))
```

And a .html like

```
<div class="status" *ngFor="let status of obs$|async">
  <div class="row">
    <b>Id: </b><span [class.change]="status[1].id">{{status[0].id}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Disabled: </b
    ><span [class.change]="status[1].disabled">{{status[0].disabled}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Virtual: </b
    ><span [class.change]="status[1].virtual">{{status[0].virtual}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Offline: </b
    ><span [class.change]="status[1].isOffline">{{status[0].isOffline}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Close: </b
    ><span [class.change]="status[1].isClosed">{{status[0].isClosed}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Open: </b
    ><span [class.change]="status[1].isOpen">{{status[0].isOpen}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcpzja?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Answer (score 0):

I made another solution:
Directive:

```
    import {
      Directive,
      ElementRef,
      Renderer2,
      EventEmitter,
      Output,
    } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appHighlight]',
    })
    export class HighlightDirective {
      private changes: MutationObserver;
    
      @Output()
      public domChange = new EventEmitter();
    
      constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    
        this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
          mutations.forEach((mutation: MutationRecord) => {
            if (element.innerText !== mutation.oldValue) {
              this.renderer.addClass(element, 'highlight');
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.renderer.removeClass(element, 'highlight');
              }, 900);
            }
          });
        });
    
        this.changes.observe(element, {
          attributes: false,
          childList: false,
          subtree: true,
          characterData: true,
          attributeOldValue: false,
          characterDataOldValue: true,
        });
      }
    }
```

Usage in div or another html tag:

```
appHighlight
```